# How can i show specific Category List?

Tags: php, categories, javascript

By this code ,it shows all the category.but i want to show specific some category(like-Officer,Training) Thanks in Advance

```
    <?php 
        // change category to your custom page slug
        $categories = get_categories(); 
        foreach ($categories as $category) {
            $option .= '<option value="'.get_option('home').'/category/'.$category->slug.'">';
            $option .= $category->cat_name;
            $option .= ' ('.$category->category_count.')';
            $option .= '</option>';
        }
        echo $option;
    ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 
    // change category to your custom page slug
    $categories = get_categories( array( 'include' => array(1, 2, 3) ) ); 
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        $option .= '<option value="'.get_option('home').'/category/'.$category->slug.'">';
        $option .= $category->cat_name;
        $option .= ' ('.$category->category_count.')';
        $option .= '</option>';
    }
    echo $option;
?>
```

**array(1, 2, 3)** is category ids.

Comment: Thank you so much,its working